# Split string by last character and save to array?

Tags: php, arrays, string, split, preg-split

I have several strings that look like:

> longname1, anotherlongname2, has1numbers2init3

I would like to use `str_split` to split off the last character of the strings. Eg:

```
Array ( [0] => longname [1] => 1 )
Array ( [0] => anotherlongname [1] => 2 )
Array ( [0] => has1numbers2init [1] => 3 )
```

I can get the number alone using `substr($string, -1);` but need to find an efficient way of retrieving the remainder of the string.

I have tried:

```
str_split($string,-1);
```

but of course this doesn't work.

Would anyone know what I could do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subtract one from the **[`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)** of your `$string` inside of **[`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)**:

```
<?php

$string = 'longname1';
print_r(str_split($string, strlen($string) - 1));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => longname
    [1] => 1
)
```

This can be seen working **[here](https://3v4l.org/uKuDp)**.

Answer (score 3):

I think that `preg_match` with an appropriate pattern works better here:

```
preg_match('/(.*?)\d+$/', "has1numbers2init123", $m);
echo $m[1];

has1numbers2init
```

Note that this solution is robust to there being more than one digit at the end of the word.

### Demo

Comment: Different from other answers, this snippet does not isolate the trimmed trailing digit.  (The question is ambiguous about whether both pieces of the input string need to be accessible.)

Answer (score 0):

Use [preg_splt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) :

```
$str = 'has1numbers2init3';

return preg_split('/(\d)$/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

See [DEMO](https://implode.io/5OCuH0)

Answer (score 0):

To safeguard against splitting too late when a string ends with an integer that is larger than 9, allow matching one or more digits before the end of the string.  This will work on all of the question's samples and strings with longer trailing numbers.

My pattern will split on the zero-width position between the last non-digit and the last one or more digits.  The `\K` "forgets" the last non-digits so that it is not consumed during the explosion.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3UZ5h))

```
$str = 'has1numbers2init33';

var_export(
    preg_split('/\D\K(?=\d+$)/', $str)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'has1numbers2init',
  1 => '33',
)
```

---

More basically, split the string on the position before the last character un the string. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/QeGqu)

```
var_export(
    preg_split('/(?=.$)/', $str)
);
```